# Transfering Javascript code from global variables to classes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to transfer my Javascript code from global variables to classes, but I got stuck with transferring data between classes. Here is the example of my old code which uses global variables.

```
var globalVar;
    
    function getDataFromServer () {
      const json = await sendToServer(data); // in sendToServer func I receive a large amount of data via json from server
      if (json) {
        globalVar = json;
        useGlobalData();
      }
    }
    
    function useGlobalData () {
      var_dump (globalVar);
      // here I can do something with globalVar
    }

getDataFromServer();
```

And here is the same code which I'm trying to implement in classes without using global variables and I got stuck here...

```
class getDataFromServer {
  serverData;

  constructor () {
          const json = await sendToServer(data); // in sendToServer func I receive a large amount of data via json from server. This data is constant and will not be changed in the future.
          if (json) {
            this.serverData = json;
            let newClass = new useGlobalData ();

          }
  }
}

class useGlobalData {
  constructor () {
    // In this class I need to use serverData data from getDataFromServer class, but I don't want to receive it again (twice) from webserver
  }
}

var serverData = new getDataFromServer ();
```

Comment: Pass it as a parameter to the new class like `let newClass = new useGlobalData(this.serverData);` and it should be a parameter in you `useGlobalData` class

Comment: This replaces one global variable with another global variable. It might be "better" to have a class with methods rather than an object that you pass to functions, but in the end you still have a global variable referencing the data. Seems to me you'd be better off with a *globalData* "class" that has a *getData* method plus other methods to do things with the data.